# google work icon displayed on react native app

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

What's the purpose of google work icon on my react native app ,how to remove it ?

As i was working with react native ,suddenly google work icon is placed on the right bottom side of my icon ,also what is the purpose of that icon.

I couldn't find anything related to this on google